# What does "not be on our way" mean?

Tags: meaning

Dave and his team protesting against war on Vietnam:

> Dave: If the police try to arrest me, I'll do what I always do and
> what I taught you to do, which is what?
>
> Man: Very calmly and very politely…Fu*ck the motherfu*kers up! They
> leave us alone and  everything's cool. They tangle, disrupt,
> intimidate, play fast and loose with the First Amendment, start
> breaking heads, then we will not **be on our way**.

What does "not be on our way" mean?

Source: The Trial of the Chicago 7 (2020)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are 'on your way' (to somewhere) you are going somewhere. "Man" is saying that if they provoke the police they will be stopped, beaten, arrested, etc, and therefore not be on their way (going away from that place).